# Show specific loader on specific AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using this JQuery code to call loader, I have a form in which 2 AJAX calls are used, one call is used within an input field and other on submit button. I am using same DIV id on both loaders but the problem here is, when AJAX call is sent through input field, the loader on submit button is also shown. Following is the JQuery code

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    $("#loading").show();
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $("#loading").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try like this

1) Have 2 boolean variables like

```
IsLoaderForInput = false;
IsLoaderForSubmit = false;
```

2) Change its value to `true`(respectively), in your function where you're using ajax.

3) Then change you code as

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function() {
    if (IsLoaderForInput) 
        $("#loading1").show();
    else 
        $("#loading2").show();  
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    if (IsLoaderForInput) 
        $("#loading1").hide();
    else 
        $("#loading2").hide();
    // reset the values
    IsLoaderForInput = false;
    IsLoaderForSubmit = false;
});
```

Hope you understand the logic.